# Play MP3s from Firefox without opening player window for every audio file

Tags: windows-7, firefox, audio

We have an offline "website" (standard static HTML) which contains links to MP3 files. We are using Windows 7 Pro 64bit and Firefox 10.

Every time I click a link, a new audio player window appears (no matter if WMP, Clementine etc). When I have many audio files on the "website", then after some time I have 10 or more player windows opened.

We tried mpeg123, but had the same problem – only CMD were opening instead of GUI windows. Is there any app able to play audio files in "hidden" mode, without creating a new session and opening a new window for every file?

Comment: Why not http://www.subsonic.org/

Comment: Does this same thing occur when you play the MP3 files locally from a standard double click play from a file?  Is the occurance specific to the HTML (local) play ?

Comment: @Zoredache: because I need it for offline use. ;-)

Comment: Subsonic can be install on your own system or internal network.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to implement a flash/html5 MP3 player rather than having the user need their own MP3 player. Not everyone has this due to licensing restrictions anyway.

This is good: http://jplayer.org/

Answer (score 1):

Install [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and opt to install the **Mozilla plugin**.

[image: Firefox plugin]

> **Note**: <s>There is a [known bug](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=97098) with the VLC plugin and recent versions of Firefox. The audio controls are not visible. So, for the
> time being, I recommend disabling the plugin if you installed it!</s>
>
> This has been **fixed** with VLC `2.0.0`!

Now, in Firefox you have two choices: to play audio files in a new tab/window using the plugin or to play them using the VLC application.

[image: Firefox > Options > Application > VLC]

I can confirm, on a clean installation of Windows 7, that only a single VLC instance is used when opening new audio files. *Using the plugin allows multiple audio streams*. If you are still getting more than one VLC window, then your problem lies with your Firefox or Windows configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try *FoxyTune* Firefox add-on:

http://www.foxytunes.com/

Check also this Mashable's article: 16 Great Music Add-Ons for Firefox

http://mashable.com/2009/03/09/firefox-music-addons/

:)